# Pattern matching warning with binary tree

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm a beginner at Haskell and am having some trouble with understanding the warnings I get. I have implemented a binary tree,

```
data Tree a = Nil | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Show, 
Read)
```

and it works fine but I get incomplete patterns warning on this code

```
get :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Maybe a
get _ Nil = Nothing
get x (Node v lt rt)
    | x == v = Just x
    | x < v = get x lt
    | x > v = get x rt
```

The pattern it wants me to match is `_ (Node _ _ _ )`. I'm not sure what this pattern means?

Comment: Can you show the warnings you get. Why do you use `AATree` instead of `Tree` in your function signature?

Comment: Sorry, the I copied the wrong code, I've changed it, it was only a difference of aatree/tree though!

Comment: warning is: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘get’: Patterns not matched: _ (Node _ _ _ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here. First of all, the datatype:

```
data Tree a = Nil | Node a (Tree left) (Tree right) deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
--                               ^ left?     ^ right?
```

In your data definition, you make use of **`left` and `right`**, but those are *not* defined in the head of the data definition, therefore these are **not type parameters**. You probably wanted to say:

```
data Tree a =   Nil
              | Node { value :: a, left :: Tree a, right :: Tree a}
              deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
```

But now we still get an error:

```
hs.hs:5:1: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘get’: Patterns not matched: _ (Node _ _ _)
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
```

The problem here is that **Haskell does not know that two values can only be `<`, `==` or `>`)**.

If you write an `instance` of `Ord`, then you have a "contact" that you will define a *total ordering*. In other words, for any two values `x` and `y`, it holds that `x < y`, `x > y` or `x == y`. The problem is however that Haskell does *not* know that. For Haskell any of the functions `(<)`, `(==)` or `(>)` can result in `True` or `False`. Therefore - since a compiler is **always conservative** - it considers the case where there are two values such that all `x < y`, `x == y` and `x > y` fail (say that you hypothetically would have written `foo x y`, `bar x y` and `qux x y` then this definitely could happens since those are three *blackbox* functions). You can resolve it by **writing `otherwise`** in the last case:

```
get :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Maybe a
get _ Nil = Nothing
get x (Node v lt rt)
    | x == v = Just x
    | x < v = get x lt
    | otherwise = get x rt
```

`otherwise` is an *alias* for `True` and therefore *there is no possibility* not to take that branch. So now the *conservative* compiler understands that, regardless what the values of `x` and `y` are, it will always take *some* branch, because if it does not take the first two, it will *certainly* take the last one.

You may think that it is weird, but since the contracts are usually not specified in a formal language (only in the documentation, so a *natural* language), the compiler has *no* means to know that: you could as a programmer decide not to respect the contracts (but note that this is a *very* bad idea). Even if you write a formal contract usually as a programmer you still can decide not to respect it and furthermore a compiler cannot always do the required logical reasoning about the formal contracts.

Comment: Thank you! @Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 2):

Willem Van Onsem has already explained the issue well. I only want to add that it *is* possible to perform a comparison between `x` and `v` in a very similar way to the posted code, whose branches are however found exhaustive by the compiler.

Instead of

```
get :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Maybe a
get _ Nil = Nothing
get x (Node v lt rt)
    | x == v = Just x
    | x < v = get x lt
    | x > v = get x rt
```

simply use

```
get :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Maybe a
get _ Nil = Nothing
get x (Node v lt rt) = case compare x v of
    EQ -> Just x
    LT -> get x lt
    GT -> get x rt
```

Indeed, `compare` is a function taking two arguments and returning a value in the enumerated type `Ordering`, which can only be `EQ` (equal), `LT` (less than), and `GT` (greater than). Since this is an algebraic type, GHC can see that all its constructors are handled by the `case`.

Further, depending on the actual type `a`, using `compare` can be more efficient. E.g., when comparing two potentially long strings, it's suboptimal to traverse them twice (if not three times, in the original code): `compare` does only a single pass to both strings and determines which order relation holds.